# Edit function in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need to change this line

```
$image = vt_resize( '', $f_image, 420, 280, true );
```

to new dimensions, but I do not know how to put this into my child theme's `functions.php` correctly.

I can't figure out the code to do this at all.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_post_media' ) )
{
    function get_post_media()
    {
        $image = '';
        if ( is_single() )
        {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
            {
                $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $f_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb );
                $alt = get_post_meta( $thumb, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
                $title = get_the_title( $thumb );
                if ( $f_image )
                {
                    if ( zget_option( 'sb_use_full_image', 'blog_options', false, 'no' ) == 'yes' )
                    {
                        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb, 'full' );
                        if ( isset( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) && !empty( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) )
                        {
                            $image = '<a data-lightbox="image" href="' . $featured_image[ 0 ] . '" class="hoverBorder pull-left full-width kl-blog-post-img"><img src="' . $featured_image[ 0 ] . '" ' . ZngetImageSizesFromUrl( $featured_image[ 0 ], true ) . ' alt="' . ZngetImageAltFromUrl( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) . '" title="' . ZngetImageTitleFromUrl( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) . '"/></a>';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $feature_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb );
                        $image = vt_resize( '', $f_image, 420, 280, true );
                        $image = '<a data-lightbox="image" href="' . $feature_image . '" class="hoverBorder pull-left kl-blog-post-img kl-blog-post--default-view" ><img src="' . $image[ 'url' ] . '" width="' . $image[ 'width' ] . '" height="' . $image[ 'height' ] . '" alt="' . $alt . '" title="' . $title . '"/></a>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy and paste all that code you already have into functions.php of your child theme and it will override the parent function.  Amend the line "$image = vt_resize( '', $f_image, 420, 280, true );" in your child theme function file and it will work.

Comment: Okay so the entire file needs to be copied into that? What about the code that is already in the child funcions php? there's some woocommerce functions in there...do I just add it under the rest of the code? 

Also - what would I put so it does not resize the image? Would rather it kept my original size - thanks!

Comment: Just add the code that you have above under the existing code in the functions.php file.  I don't know how the function vt_resize() works it's not a core WordPress function so I can't help if I can't see the source code for it.  However, according to the function is you set the option "sb_use_full_image" to yes in your theme options it will use the full size image.

Comment: Thanks very much! Sorted it now changed dimensions. I changed sb_use_full_image to yes and it didnt work. I then tried it to 'true' and 'yes' but still resized. Tried deleting resize code and it got rid of the image. No worries though im a lot further ahead now :D Thanks!

Comment: You need to set it in the admin dashboard options page not in the functions.php file for the full size image.  It should be a checkbox somewhere in the theme options page.

Answer (score 0):

This code will force the function to use your full size image always.  However, it's better to set the theme option in the dashboard to force full size images.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_post_media' ) ) {
    function get_post_media()
    {
        $image = '';
        if ( is_single() )
        {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
            {
                $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $f_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb );
                $alt = get_post_meta( $thumb, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
                $title = get_the_title( $thumb );
                if ( $f_image )
                {
                    $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb, 'full' );
                    if ( isset( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) && !empty( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) )
                    {
                        $image = '<a data-lightbox="image" href="' . $featured_image[ 0 ] .
                            '" class="hoverBorder pull-left full-width kl-blog-post-img"><img src="' .
                            $featured_image[ 0 ] . '" ' . ZngetImageSizesFromUrl( $featured_image[ 0 ], true ) . ' alt="' . ZngetImageAltFromUrl( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) .
                            '" title="' . ZngetImageTitleFromUrl( $featured_image[ 0 ] ) . '"/></a>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```